# Qual seria a chave única natural ideal associada a uma pessoa?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelagem

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema cuja uma das tabelas representa **pessoas**. Naturalmente, o documento mais preciso para representar unicamente uma pessoa é o CPF. No entanto, o sistema prevê a possibilidade de que pessoas estrangeiras residentes no Brasil possam se cadastrar.

Pessoas estrangeiras não têm obrigatoriedade de emitir um CPF. Desta forma, penso em algumas possibilidades:

- Passaporte
- RNE

Apesar desses documentos conseguirem representar de forma única uma pessoa, temos os seguinte problemas:

- O Passaporte, apesar de ser comum entre não-estrangeiros e estrangeiros, não é obrigatório, e creio que a maioria dos usuários do sistema não possuiriam.
- O RNE é obrigatório, mas apenas para estrangeiros.

---

Considerando a situação acima, qual a melhor solução para representar unicamente uma pessoa em minha base de dados?

- Utilizar ambos os campos CPF e RNE, obrigando que a coluna possua **um ou o outro**.
- Utilizar outra chave única (citar qual e explicar o motivo).

Comment: me parece que está confundindo um pouco os conceitos de chave com uma validação unique. A chave pode ser um campo numérico sequencial que vai garantir a cada registro um valor único. A chave é um requisito do banco e não necessariamente precisa ser um atributo de negócio, por isso não precisa ser qualquer campo que o negócio necessita, como nomes, datas ou documentos. Sugiro criar um simples campo numérico que se incremente sozinho, e colocar *constraints* nos outros campos para que não se repita e estará resolvido o problema

Comment: Não há confusão. Não estou me referindo à chave primária não natural do banco. Essa será feita de forma incremental. Mas sim de uma chave auxiliar única (unique index) que me permita representar de forma natural e única uma pessoa. Posso fazer uma validação no backend sem dificuldades, mas estou questionando a forma correta de fazer isso no modelo de dados do banco.

Comment: se já tem uma chave primária incremental, a única validação no nível do banco que pode ser feita é definir um campo como *unique*. Agora se o campo pode conter valores nulos isso não será possível, então terá de validar a nível de código

Comment: uma outra alternativa seria criar um campo único para o documento, tanto passaporte quanto rne, e um outro campo dizendo qual o tipo do documento, assim o documento nunca seria nulo, e poderia criar um índice unique com o tipo documento+documento, acho que seria uma boa ideia

Comment: É uma boa pergunta! Geralmente não uso essas informações como chave, porém uso um UUID ou um ID numérico normal, juntamente com um campo único de e-mail.

Comment: Uma chave artificial sequencial nestes casos pode ser uma solução , dependendo do caso uma tabela com a documentação , cpf , rg , pis , passaporte , cns , brevê , cnh ... como você não disse a natureza do sistema creio que o melhor seja ser genêrico , a documentação pode ter um tratamento de unicidade dentro da sua natureza para garantir a unicidade.

Comment: @RicardoPontual creio que essa sua segunda opção seja o que mais se aproxima do que eu preciso. O único problema seria o caso de um estrangeiro que possui um RNE e resolve fazer um CPF e se cadastra com ambos os dados. Mas esse caso é extremamente raro e fácil de validar no backend sem preocupação.

Answer (score 1):

Você está partindo da premissa que a única solução para o seu problema é usar um campo contendo um código numérico extraído de um documento oficial como chave única porém, se esquece quem nem toda **pessoa** possui os mesmos documentos.

Se estamos falando de **qualquer pessoa**, brasileira ou estrangeira, usar números de documentos não é uma boa ideia pois:

- A mesma pessoa pode possuir mais de um CPF;
- Nem toda pessoa é de origem brasileira;
- Nem todo brasileiro possui um passaporte;
- Nem todo estrangeiro possui um CPF;

Se estamos falando de **pessoa**, temos que considerar atributos naturais de uma **pessoa**, tais como:

- Nome;
- Nome da Mãe;
- Data de Nascimento;
- Estado de Nascimento;
- Cidade de Nascimento;

E até mesmo:

- País de Nascimento;
- Planeta de nascimento;
- Galáxia de Nascimento;

Sim, irmãos gêmeos com nomes idênticos podem ser uma exceção. Mas, que tipo de mãe daria o mesmo nome para dois filhos diferentes ?!